# How to have different edge weights but same edge length in network diagram?

Tags: python, networkx

I am working with networkx in Python. I am facing an issue where I want to give different weightage to the different edges with same edge length for all.

Although with this code, with different weightage to edges, the length is also changing, which is undesirable.

I need some help with it.

Thanks in advance.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

df = pd.DataFrame({'from': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '4', '4'], 'to': ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'], 'value': ['0.5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']})
df['value'] = pd.Categorical(df['value'])
df['value'].cat.codes


G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'from', 'to', create_using=nx.Graph())

cmap = plt.cm.cool
vmax = float(max(df['value']))
vmin = float(min(df['value']))
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1, 2,  weight=5)
G.add_edge(2, 3,  weight=0.5)
G.add_edge(3, 4,  weight=0.5)
G.add_edge(4, 5,  weight=0.5)
G.add_edge(4, 6,  weight=0.5)
G.add_edge(4, 7,  weight=0.5)
edges = G.edges()
weights = [G[u][v]['weight'] for u,v in edges]

nc = nx.draw_networkx(G, with_labels=True, node_color='yellow', node_size=700, edge_color=df['value'].cat.codes, width=weights, edge_cmap=cmap, font_size=10, font_color='black', font_weight='bold')

sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin = vmin, vmax = vmax))
sm._A = []
plt.colorbar(sm)
plt.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default, a spring layout is used to layout the nodes. This often is the most pleasing. Also default, the spring layout uses the 'weight' attribute of the edges for their length. The *heavier*, the closer together. However, you can add your own attributes and tell spring_layout to use those. I named it 'draw_weight', but any name will do. You can also put it to None, which weights every edge equally (`pos=nx.spring_layout(G, weight=None)`).

You can also experiment with other layout algorithms as mentioned in [the documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.11/reference/drawing.html#module-networkx.drawing.layout) to replace the default spring_layout.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

df = pd.DataFrame({'from': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '4', '4'], 'to': ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'], 'value': ['0.5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']})
df['value'] = pd.Categorical(df['value'])
df['value'].cat.codes


G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'from', 'to', create_using=nx.Graph())

cmap = plt.cm.cool
vmax = float(max(df['value']))
vmin = float(min(df['value']))
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1, 2,  weight=5,    draw_weight=1)
G.add_edge(2, 3,  weight=0.5,  draw_weight=1)
G.add_edge(3, 4,  weight=0.5,  draw_weight=1)
G.add_edge(4, 5,  weight=0.5,  draw_weight=1)
G.add_edge(4, 6,  weight=0.5,  draw_weight=1)
G.add_edge(4, 7,  weight=0.5,  draw_weight=1)
edges = G.edges()
weights = [G[u][v]['weight'] for u,v in edges]

nc = nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=nx.spring_layout(G, weight='draw_weight'),  with_labels=True, node_color='yellow', node_size=700, edge_color=df['value'].cat.codes, width=weights, edge_cmap=cmap, font_size=10, font_color='black', font_weight='bold')

sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin = vmin, vmax = vmax))
sm._A = []
plt.colorbar(sm)
plt.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

[image: The resulting graph layout]

Note that the edge lengths are never exactly equal, because the spring_layout tries to combine two strategies: to have nodes nicely separated and edge lengths close to the desired ones. For this example, the shell_layout would also look nice, but probably the idea is to have more complicated graphs. Some experimentation will be required.

Comment: If I understand correctly, OP wants every edge's length showing in the graph is equal. Specifying `spring_layout` with option `weight` will not achieve this objective.

Comment: @AndyL.  giving the option `weight=None` makes the spring layout have the lengths more or less equal. Note that they are never exactly equal, because the spring_layout tries to combine strategies to have nodes nicely separated and edge lengths are close to the desired ones.

Comment: Yes. That is what I think. `spring_layout` bases on pulling strength of edges and pushing strength of nodes. So, it is impossible to draw equal length edges in the graph. I agree approximately is possible, but exactly equal is impossible. OP question gives me impression that he wants exactly equal.

Comment: To have exactly equal lengths, the given layout algorithms are not adequate. One could copy the implementation of the spring_layout and try to play with its priorities. Probably the main concern of the OP is that in this example node 1 and node 2 were too close together to see the edge and its color.